# Why can't I put drop down menu under a button?

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu

I am so desperate right now. Have tried 2 days to solve this but still no avail. The dropdown menu cannot be put under the situation and the exercise button correctly. It shows on the left hand-side of the navbar instead of the bottom of the button, which may because i used float left at line 19 CSS in fiddle:

```
.navbar a,.sit,.exercise {
   float:left; 
}
```

class "navbar" is for the whole navbar

class"dropdown1" is for the followings :class"sit" is for the button "situation", class"situ" is for the dropdown menu in "sit"

class"dropdown2" is for the followings :class"exercise" is for the button "exercise", class"exec" is for the dropdown menu in "exercise"

I have tried to put position: relative under class"sit" and class"exercise". However, the result is that a scrollbar shows up in the dropdown menu and you have to scroll it down to see the whole menu. The position doesn't even change!

here is the code in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zo0raL86/

I expect the dropdown menu can be shown under the right button. Really hope that you can give me a helping hand! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you've set all your floats on the children of the elements you actually want to float. 
For example:
You have

```
.navbar a,.sit,.exercise {
    float:left;
    width: 32.78%;
}
```

Whereas the float:left; and the width should be on their parent elements `.i3`, `.dropdown1`, and `.dropdown2` like so ...

```
.i3,
.dropdown1,
.dropdown2 {
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
}
```

This will solve the basics of your problem and the additional width problem you've expressed in your fiddle.

Better still set the widths of `.sit` and `.exercise` to 100%.

I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ehqva4ry/1/) so you can see the code in situ.

Comment: it works!! Thank you so much!!! Don't know how to express how thankful I am!! Guess I really need to focus more on the relationship between parent and children elements.  
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```css
.navbar > div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32.78%;
}
```

Then add some pixels to the `top`-Value of `.situ` and `.exec` then it will be display right under the button.

I also updated your html.

```html
<div class="navbar">
   <div class="i3">
     <a href="About.asp">About</a>
   </div>

   <div class="dropdown1">    
    <a href="#">Situation
      <div class="situ">
        <a href="situation1.asp">s1</a>
        <a href="situation2.asp">s2</a>
        <a href="situation3.asp">s3</a>
      </div>       
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="dropdown2">
    <a href="#">Exercise
      <div class="exec">
        <a href="exercise1.asp">e1</a>
        <a href="exercise2.asp">e2</a>
        <a href="exercise3.asp">e3</a>
      </div>       
    </a>
   </div>     
</div>
```

Remove the `bottom` Value from your dropdowns and add

```css
.situ, .exec{
  top: 123px;
}
```

The value should be the sum of your `margin-top` and `height` to fit smoothly under the navigation.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying! I have added the code, however, the result is still a little bit away my expectation......I expect the drop down menu shows right under the button but now it shows on top of the button...

here is the amended code   https://jsfiddle.net/o0dc4wL8/  

have add the code you provided and bottom value to .situ  and top value to    .exec.  The dropdown menu which has been added bottom value is slightly away from the button.  I am really grateful for your help!!